# DOTS DOTS in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to interpret some SQL query at a new workplace. What is the meaning of dots dots `..` in the query shown here?

```
SELECT AAAA
FROM RMPROD..LDC_ACCOUNT
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`RMPROD` - is your database name
`LDC_ACCOUNT` - is your table name

what is missing? Schema name is missing, it means, that SQL Server will try to find your table in your default schema.

Default schema is often `dbo`.

If it's right, your query means

```
SELECT *
FROM RMPROD.dbo.LDC_ACCOUNT
```